# Error while accessing tridion content manager

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Getting below error while accessing SDL Tridion Content Manager (SDL Tridion version 2011). Did anyone face this issue before?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:Error xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ErrorCode="8004035A" Category="23" Source="Kernel" Severity="1">
  <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004035A" Cause="false" MessageID="4394">
    <![CDATA[Unable to Initialize TDSE object.]]>
    <tcm:Token>RESID_4537</tcm:Token>
    <tcm:Token>TDSE</tcm:Token>
  </tcm:Line>
  <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004035A" Cause="true" MessageID="16246">
    <![CDATA[The license is invalid. Please contact SDL Tridion Customer Support: EasyLicenser error -12]]>
    <tcm:Token>EasyLicenser error -12</tcm:Token>
  </tcm:Line>
  <tcm:Details>
    <tcm:CallStack>
      <tcm:Location>Licensing.StartupLicenseCheck</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Security.InitializeUserContext</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>UtilitiesTDS.GetUserContext</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>TDSE.Initialize</tcm:Location>
    </tcm:CallStack>
  </tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should consider asking this over on [the Tridion Stack Exhchange website](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/).  You are more likely to get a response from the Tridion experts there.

However, looking at your error message:

> The license is invalid. Please contact SDL Tridion Customer Support:
>   EasyLicenser error -12

It would appear that there is an issue with your license file.  I would suggest that you check that the license you are using is correct (they are specific to a particular server and are often based on the number of CPUs and possibly the number of Users and/or Publications) and contact the Tridion Support team if you are unable to resolve yourself.